# How to change owners for files in the mounted path within VM (using vagrant)?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, debian, nfs, vagrant

I would appreciate for the help.

I have mac os as a local machine and VirtualBox + vagrant (with a debian 7 on the board) as a guest machine.

every time I run any website on the VM a got an error:

**Warning: session_start(): Session data file is not created by your uid**

I guess the reason is in the owner on the local machine.

My Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/Volumes/USB/VM/projects/", "/var/www/", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=777"] }
```

"/Volumes/USB/VM/projects/" in on the flash drive and has owner _unknown but I can change it.

While nfs is in process I cannot change owner on the guest machine.

> chown: changing ownership of
>   ‘./Locale.php’:
>   Operation not permitted